# how to filter json to combine results

Tags: arrays, json

i have a json which is as below which i need to combine before i can use it in my code

I've tried array prototype but could only filter either product id or the city,

```
  question = [{ store_id: 489, product_id: "empty", city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: "empty", city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 489, product_id: 123123, city: "empty" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: 456456, city: "empty" }]

    var newArray = question.filter(function (el) {
      return el.store_id != "empty" &&
      el.city != "empty" 
    });
    console.log(newArray);
```

i need to combine the object on the basis of store_id and get an updated json where there is no "empty" in product_id or city

```
  answer = [{ store_id: 489, product_id: 123123, city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: 456456, city: "Delhi" }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a new array:

```
var answer = [];
```

Then fill it with the objects in your source array, copying only the properties we want to keep:

```
var answer = [];
for (let store of question)
{
    let newEntry = {};
    for (let prop in store)
    {
      if ( store[prop] !== "empty" ) newEntry[prop] = store[prop];
    }
    answer.push(newEntry);
}
console.log(answer);
```

Output:

```
0: Object { store_id: 489, city: "Delhi" }
1: Object { store_id: 472, city: "Delhi" }
2: Object { store_id: 489, product_id: 123123 }
3: Object { store_id: 472, product_id: 456456 }
length: 4
```

This is a start - no empty properties. But no merging either. So now we can add that: look for an existing entry in our result with the right store_id and merge the non-empty properties into it:

```
var answer = [];
for (let store of question)
{
    let newEntry = {};
    for (let prop in store)
    {
      if ( store[prop] !== "empty" ) newEntry[prop] = store[prop];
    }

    let existing = answer.find(s => s.store_id === store.store_id);
    if ( existing )
      Object.assign(existing, newEntry);
    else 
        answer.push(newEntry);
}
console.log(answer);
```

Output:

```
0: Object { store_id: 489, city: "Delhi", product_id: 123123 }
1: Object { store_id: 472, city: "Delhi", product_id: 456456 }
length: 2
```

One last step you might want to add, to filter out any objects that may not have been fully-populated - there are none in your example though:

```
answer = answer.filter(s => s.city && s.product_id);
```

And all together:

```
var question = [{ store_id: 489, product_id: "empty", city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: "empty", city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 489, product_id: 123123, city: "empty" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: 456456, city: "empty" }];

var answer = [];
for (let store of question)
{
    let newEntry = {};
    for (let prop in store)
    {
      if ( store[prop] !== "empty" ) newEntry[prop] = store[prop];
    }

    let existing = answer.find(s => s.store_id === store.store_id);
    if ( existing )
      Object.assign(existing, newEntry);
    else 
        answer.push(newEntry);
}
answer = answer.filter(s => s.city && s.product_id);
console.log(answer);
```

Now you have a working solution, but it isn't very efficient; if you have a large amount of data to process, you'll want to do as much processing as possible in a single pass, as in this version from David Winder:

```
question = [{ store_id: 489, product_id: "empty", city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: "empty", city: "Delhi" },
  { store_id: 489, product_id: 123123, city: "empty" },
  { store_id: 472, product_id: 456456, city: "empty" }];

let ans = {};
for (let key in question) {
  let value =  question[key]; // get the value by key
  if (value.store_id in ans) { // if already exist
      if (ans[value.store_id].product_id == "empty") // update product_id 
          ans[value.store_id].product_id = value.product_id;
      if (ans[value.store_id].city == "empty") // update city
          ans[value.store_id].city = value.city;
  } else
    ans[value.store_id] = value;
}

console.log(Object.keys(ans).map(i => ans[i]));
```

This will output:

```
[ { store_id: 472, product_id: 456456, city: 'Delhi' },
  { store_id: 489, product_id: 123123, city: 'Delhi' } ]
```

Comment: Oh yes, this could be much, much more efficient. My primary goal here was to break down the problem enough that the asker could hopefully learn to think through it on their own. But certainly if I was processing more than a few dozen records I would lean toward something closer to what you've demonstrated.

Comment: So I suggest you add my `O(n)` solution to your answer To make it more complete (and then I will delete my post)

Comment: Happy to, @David